# React - onclick function is running on page load

Tags: reactjs, onclick

the code in the file is simple. it is imported into another file that places it in a slider container. That all works I'm just having trouble with the onClick function running on page load instead of on click.

```
import React from 'react';
import M_IMAGE from 'assets/image.png';

function openImage() {
   window.open(M_IMAGE);
}

export const slider = {
   data: [
     {
      content: (
          <img src={M_IMAGE} onClick="openImage" />
      )
     }
   ]
  }
```

I have tried this.openImage.bind and many other variants I have seen online.

Comment: <img src={M_IMAGE} onClick={()=> window.open(M_IMAGE)} />

Comment: thanks! this worked (after I deleted the function from the code)

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the curly braces around the `onClick`'s event handler and need to assign it like below:

```
<img src={M_IMAGE} onClick={openImage}
```

Comment: same result. run's on page load instead of on click

Answer (score 0):

UKS commented on the post with an response leading to the fix.

I had to delete the function because it existing caused it to run on load and change the code to

<img src={M_IMAGE} onClick={()=> window.open(M_IMAGE)} />